# Displaying the labels vertically

Tags: swing, awt, optaplanner

Please, I want to display the labels' text vertically.

Also I want the column header to be displayed vertically.

actually, I tried to use:

```
public static final String LOGO_PATH = "/org/optaplanner/examples/curriculumcourse/swingui/curriculumCourseLogo.png";

private final TimeTablePanel<Room, Period> roomsPanel;
private final TimeTablePanel<Teacher, Period> teachersPanel;
private final TimeTablePanel<Curriculum, Period> curriculaPanel;

public CurriculumCoursePanel() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    roomsPanel = new TimeTablePanel<Room, Period>();
    tabbedPane.add("Rooms", new JScrollPane(roomsPanel));
    teachersPanel = new TimeTablePanel<Teacher, Period>();
    tabbedPane.add("Teachers", new JScrollPane(teachersPanel));
    curriculaPanel = new TimeTablePanel<Curriculum, Period>();
    tabbedPane.add("Curricula", new JScrollPane(curriculaPanel));
    add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setPreferredSize(PREFERRED_SCROLLABLE_VIEWPORT_SIZE);
}

@Override
public boolean isWrapInScrollPane() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isRefreshScreenDuringSolving() {
    return true;
}

private CourseSchedule getCourseSchedule() {
    return (CourseSchedule) solutionBusiness.getSolution();
}

public void resetPanel(Solution solution) {
    roomsPanel.reset();
    teachersPanel.reset();
    curriculaPanel.reset();
    CourseSchedule courseSchedule = (CourseSchedule) solution;
    defineGrid(courseSchedule);
    fillCells(courseSchedule);
    repaint(); // Hack to force a repaint of TimeTableLayout during "refresh screen while solving"
}

private void defineGrid(CourseSchedule courseSchedule) {
    JButton footprint = new JButton("LinLetGre1-0");
    footprint.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    int footprintWidth = footprint.getPreferredSize().width;

    roomsPanel.defineColumnHeaderByKey(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1); // Day header
    roomsPanel.defineColumnHeaderByKey(HEADER_COLUMN); // Period header
    for (Room room : courseSchedule.getRoomList()) {
        roomsPanel.defineColumnHeader(room, footprintWidth);
    }
    roomsPanel.defineColumnHeader(null, footprintWidth); // Unassigned

    teachersPanel.defineColumnHeaderByKey(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1); // Day header
    teachersPanel.defineColumnHeaderByKey(HEADER_COLUMN); // Period header
    for (Teacher teacher : courseSchedule.getTeacherList()) {
        teachersPanel.defineColumnHeader(teacher, footprintWidth);
    }

    curriculaPanel.defineColumnHeaderByKey(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1); // Day header
    curriculaPanel.defineColumnHeaderByKey(HEADER_COLUMN); // Period header
    for (Curriculum curriculum : courseSchedule.getCurriculumList()) {
        curriculaPanel.defineColumnHeader(curriculum, footprintWidth);
    }

    roomsPanel.defineRowHeaderByKey(HEADER_ROW); // Room header
    teachersPanel.defineRowHeaderByKey(HEADER_ROW); // Teacher header
    curriculaPanel.defineRowHeaderByKey(HEADER_ROW); // Curriculum header
    for (Period period : courseSchedule.getPeriodList()) {
        roomsPanel.defineRowHeader(period);
        teachersPanel.defineRowHeader(period);
        curriculaPanel.defineRowHeader(period);
    }
    roomsPanel.defineRowHeader(null); // Unassigned period
    teachersPanel.defineRowHeader(null); // Unassigned period
    curriculaPanel.defineRowHeader(null); // Unassigned period
}

private void fillCells(CourseSchedule courseSchedule) {
    roomsPanel.addCornerHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, HEADER_ROW, createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Day")));
    roomsPanel.addCornerHeader(HEADER_COLUMN, HEADER_ROW, createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Time")));
    fillRoomCells(courseSchedule);
    teachersPanel.addCornerHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, HEADER_ROW, createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Day")));
    teachersPanel.addCornerHeader(HEADER_COLUMN, HEADER_ROW, createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Time")));
    fillTeacherCells(courseSchedule);
    curriculaPanel.addCornerHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, HEADER_ROW, createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Day")));
    curriculaPanel.addCornerHeader(HEADER_COLUMN, HEADER_ROW, createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Time")));
    fillCurriculumCells(courseSchedule);
    fillDayCells(courseSchedule);
    fillLectureCells(courseSchedule);
}

private void fillRoomCells(CourseSchedule courseSchedule) {
    for (Room room : courseSchedule.getRoomList()) {
        roomsPanel.addColumnHeader(room, HEADER_ROW,
                createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(room.getLabel(), SwingConstants.CENTER)));
    }
    roomsPanel.addColumnHeader(null, HEADER_ROW,
            createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Unassigned", SwingConstants.CENTER)));
}

private void fillTeacherCells(CourseSchedule courseSchedule) {
    for (Teacher teacher : courseSchedule.getTeacherList()) {
        teachersPanel.addColumnHeader(teacher, HEADER_ROW,
                createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(teacher.getLabel(), SwingConstants.CENTER)));
    }
}

private void fillCurriculumCells(CourseSchedule courseSchedule) {
    for (Curriculum curriculum : courseSchedule.getCurriculumList()) {
        curriculaPanel.addColumnHeader(curriculum, HEADER_ROW,
                createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(curriculum.getLabel(), SwingConstants.CENTER)));
    }
}

private void fillDayCells(CourseSchedule courseSchedule) {
    for (Day day : courseSchedule.getDayList()) {
        Period dayStartPeriod = day.getPeriodList().get(0);
        Period dayEndPeriod = day.getPeriodList().get(day.getPeriodList().size() - 1);
        roomsPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, dayStartPeriod, HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, dayEndPeriod,
                createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(day.getLabel())));
        teachersPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, dayStartPeriod, HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, dayEndPeriod,
                createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(day.getLabel())));
        curriculaPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, dayStartPeriod, HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, dayEndPeriod,
                createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(day.getLabel())));
        for (Period period : day.getPeriodList()) {
            roomsPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN, period,
                    createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(period.getTimeslot().getLabel())));
            teachersPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN, period,
                    createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(period.getTimeslot().getLabel())));
            curriculaPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN, period,
                    createHeaderPanel(new JLabel(period.getTimeslot().getLabel())));
        }
    }
    roomsPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, null, HEADER_COLUMN, null,
            createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Unassigned")));
    teachersPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, null, HEADER_COLUMN, null,
            createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Unassigned")));
    curriculaPanel.addRowHeader(HEADER_COLUMN_GROUP1, null, HEADER_COLUMN, null,
            createHeaderPanel(new JLabel("Unassigned")));
}

private void fillLectureCells(CourseSchedule courseSchedule) {
    TangoColorFactory tangoColorFactory = new TangoColorFactory();
    for (Lecture lecture : courseSchedule.getLectureList()) {
        Color lectureColor = tangoColorFactory.pickColor(lecture.getCourse());
        roomsPanel.addCell(lecture.getRoom(), lecture.getPeriod(),
                createButton(lecture, lectureColor));
        teachersPanel.addCell(lecture.getTeacher(), lecture.getPeriod(),
                createButton(lecture, lectureColor));
        for (Curriculum curriculum : lecture.getCurriculumList()) {
            curriculaPanel.addCell(curriculum, lecture.getPeriod(),
                    createButton(lecture, lectureColor));
        }
    }
}

private JPanel createHeaderPanel(JLabel label) {
    JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    headerPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    headerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(TangoColorFactory.ALUMINIUM_5),
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2)));
    return headerPanel;
}

private JButton createButton(Lecture lecture, Color color) {
    JButton button = new JButton(new LectureAction(lecture));
    button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    button.setBackground(color);
    if (lecture.isLocked()) {
        button.setIcon(CommonIcons.LOCKED_ICON);
    }
    return button;
}

private class LectureAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Lecture lecture;

    public LectureAction(Lecture lecture) {
        super(lecture.getLabel());
        this.lecture = lecture;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JPanel listFieldsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        listFieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Period:"));
        List<Period> periodList = getCourseSchedule().getPeriodList();
        // Add 1 to array size to add null, which makes the entity unassigned
        JComboBox periodListField = new JComboBox(
                periodList.toArray(new Object[periodList.size() + 1]));
        periodListField.setRenderer(new LabeledComboBoxRenderer());
        periodListField.setSelectedItem(lecture.getPeriod());
        listFieldsPanel.add(periodListField);
        listFieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Room:"));
        List<Room> roomList = getCourseSchedule().getRoomList();
        // Add 1 to array size to add null, which makes the entity unassigned
        JComboBox roomListField = new JComboBox(
                roomList.toArray(new Object[roomList.size() + 1]));
        roomListField.setRenderer(new LabeledComboBoxRenderer());
        roomListField.setSelectedItem(lecture.getRoom());
        listFieldsPanel.add(roomListField);
        listFieldsPanel.add(new JLabel("Locked:"));
        JCheckBox lockedField = new JCheckBox("immovable during planning");
        lockedField.setSelected(lecture.isLocked());
        listFieldsPanel.add(lockedField);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(CurriculumCoursePanel.this.getRootPane(), listFieldsPanel,
                "Select period and room", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            Period toPeriod = (Period) periodListField.getSelectedItem();
            if (lecture.getPeriod() != toPeriod) {
                solutionBusiness.doChangeMove(lecture, "period", toPeriod);
            }
            Room toRoom = (Room) roomListField.getSelectedItem();
            if (lecture.getRoom() != toRoom) {
                solutionBusiness.doChangeMove(lecture, "room", toRoom);
            }
            boolean toLocked = lockedField.isSelected();
            if (lecture.isLocked() != toLocked) {
                if (solutionBusiness.isSolving()) {
                    logger.error("Not doing user change because the solver is solving.");
                    return;
                }
                lecture.setLocked(toLocked);
            }
            solverAndPersistenceFrame.resetScreen();
        }
    }

}
```

}

I've tried to change the SwingConstants.CENTER to be SwingConstants.VERTICAL, but the following error is received:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: horizontalAlignment
at javax.swing.JLabel.checkHorizontalKey(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLabel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLabel.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

what I need is to display the labels to be written as in Excel when you align the cell's contents to be displayed from top to bottom as if it has been rotated 90 degree.

Comment: and what was the output when you tried that code?

Comment: I got that error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: horizontalAlignment
 at javax.swing.JLabel.checkHorizontalKey(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JLabel.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JLabel.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please update your answer with that output, and please also include more code from your solution, there is not enough code there at the moment to see what is causing the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll do this immediately

Comment: At which point in your own code (not the JLABEL class) does the exception get thrown? You should be able to find this if you step through the running code with a debugger.

Comment: Firstly I want to know if the way I tried is the wright one to achieve my aim or not. and if not what is the correct way to do what I want?

Comment: As far as I  can see, this attempt  should achieve what you want.

Comment: This code is for the Curriculum Course example, but I want to change the display (GUI) of this example.

Comment: So what you have done should work. As it does not, you need to debug it with a debugger, which we cannot do for you :)