# How to align JLabel content vertically?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

In Optaplanner's curriculum course example, I want to use the "fill cell" method in the example but with aligning the content of the cell vertically to appear if I had rotated it 90 degree.

I was thinking if we change the SwingConstants of the label it will work but that doesn't happen with me.

was

```
    SwingConstants.CENTER
```

tried

```
    SwingConstants.VERTICAL
```

If any one can help me.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"In the curriculum course example.."*  You say that like we should know what it means!  Give a link..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying the labels vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667687/displaying-the-labels-vertically)

Comment: approximately wright, what is the answer please?